# Firestore long get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase and ReactJS to create a website that uses Firestore.  When I read from Firestore using the following Javascript code, it is successful, however, there is an additional GET request that happens over a minute after refreshing the page.

```
firestore
  .collection("users")
  .doc(uid)
  .get()
  .then(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
      console.error("User " + uid + " does not exist. Cannot retrieve document");
    } else {
      const { avatar, displayName } = doc.data();
      this.setState({ avatar: avatar, displayName: displayName });
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("Error getting document", err);
  });
```

[image: Firefox screenshot]

If I refresh the page before this final GET, I get a warning Cross-Origin Request Blocked in the console.  I still never have problems obtaining the data from Firestore.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1beta1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects%2Fsword-pear%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&gsessionid=QbGcouT4k6BUq5C33CSi25Ih6UQR6QI2&VER=8&RID=rpc&SID=wLKF3u5yBNBdMKhPjNHJwQ&CI=0&AID=6&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=7mjvphigpy5i&t=2. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

I'm assuming the server is trying to still send data to the original web page before the refresh, but I do not know why the GET is taking so long if I get the data within the first milliseconds anyway.

Comment: I suspect the delayed request is just part of the protocol that Firestore uses, and is part of its attempts to keep the connection alive, so that subsequents go faster.

Comment: That makes sense to me.  I was hoping this was similar to what other people experience in their applications, but if it there isn't any underlying issues, I can live with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds mostly expected. Firestore is optimized for realtime communication with the backend and accomplishes this by using a form of long-polling which involves long-standing GET requests.  So even though you're only calling `get()`, internally the SDK spins up a long-polling connection to the backend in case you perform subsequent `get()` or `onSnapshot()` calls.  I believe if you don't perform any more requests for ~1 minute, then the connection will be cleaned up and you won't see any more GET requests unless you perform another operation.

I can't explain exactly why the browser logs the "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" message on page reload, but this should be benign and can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

it's at first the `localhost` and then a cross-origin `GET` request, which seems to time out. running that script from Firebase Hosting would make it a legit non cross-origin request. the problem is mixing up development and live environment, instead of using an emulator, which runs on `localhost`.

when updating the Google Cloud SDK (alias `gcloud` command) before, I've seen this:

```
Cloud Firestore Emulator
▪ Release Cloud Firestore Emulator version 1.2.1
  ◆ This is the first beta release of the emulator.
```

which would be a way to circumvent the cross-origin request, without permitting it.

see the [Web Origin Concept](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-abarth-origin-09).

Comment: Unfortunately, it does still behave this way when deployed to Firebase.  I did originally believed that was the issue too. However, when the page is initially loaded, it does not display the warning.  The warning shows up if you refresh within that 60 second time span

Comment: @Acais have you tried running the emulator locally? the problem is that with HTML one cannot send out the HTTP headers to permit CORS, while in pure JS, this is only supported by Internet Explorer. no matter when the error message is being shown, the fact that it is being shown hints for a cross-origin situation.